# Good buffersize for a Local Proxy Server

Tags: c#, http, proxy, protocol-buffers

I'm researching for a good buffersize for my local proxy server written in c#. The buffer is a byte-array and used to store the received parts of a HTTP-Response and HTTP-Request. I know, that it should not be too small (due to the rising number of socket.receive calls). If I choose a too large number it decreases perfomance aswell (I read it somewhere, but cannot remember the reason). Can you tell me a good buffer size. A reference to a prestigous web-site would be fine?

Comment: Take a look at this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811006/what-is-a-good-buffer-size-for-socket-programming

Comment: Thanks! I was searching for similar questions, but did not find this one. It solved my question. The only thing I was missing in those answeres is a reference. I need it for a elaboration.