# Java Socket Inputstream Reading Wrong Data

Tags: java

Can anyone tell what wrong with this code, what I done is that

1. Client send image data which is uchar array from c++.
2. Java server receives this data using server socket and store as byte array.

Here is the code...

```
   private ServerSocket serverSocket;
   InputStream in;
   int imageSize=300;//921600;//expected image size 640X480X3
   public imageReciver(int port) throws IOException {
      serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
    }


        Socket server = null;
        server = serverSocket.accept();
        in = server.getInputStream();
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte buffer[] = new byte[100];

        int remainingBytes = imageSize; //
        while (remainingBytes > 0) {
        int bytesRead = in.read(buffer);
        if (bytesRead < 0) {
         throw new IOException("Unexpected end of data");
         }
        baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        remainingBytes -= bytesRead;
        }
        in.close();

        byte imageByte[] = new byte[imageSize];         
        imageByte = baos.toByteArray();   
        baos.close();
```

While reading from `inputstream in` I am getting negative value on `buffer`.

Comment: Did you verify the size of the image?

Comment: Yes I am sending 300 bytes exactly...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is:

Java's byte is signed and you are sending unsigned bytes.

From [Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html):

> byte: The byte data type is an **8-bit signed two's complement integer**.
>   It has a minimum value of -128 and a maximum value of 127 (inclusive).
>   The byte data type can be useful for saving memory in large arrays,
>   where the memory savings actually matters. They can also be used in
>   place of int where their limits help to clarify your code; the fact
>   that a variable's range is limited can serve as a form of
>   documentation.

You can try something like:

```
short bVal = /*signed byte*/;
if (bVal < 0) 
   bVal = bVal + 256; //Convert to positive
```

**Edit:**
 As pointed out by @Aubin, a short will be a better choice instead of an int.

Answer (score 0):

The representation of a data as signed or unsigned is a human convention. This convention is used by the processor when arithmetic is used.

It's not the case here: it's simple read and write and the fact the bit 7 is used as negative flag or not as no effect.

Reading a socket and writing a file may be done with byte buffer or better with [ByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html). [I suggest a buffer size of 8K](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811006/what-is-a-good-buffer-size-for-socket-programming).

Rewriting the code using [java.nio.channels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/package-summary.html) may be better.