# Client server socket C#

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I am working on socket C#. I've implemented a client server application using socket, but the problem is that the client doesn't receive all data sent by the server.

Here is the client application code. What should I do so that it would receive all data sent by the server?

```
strRecieved = "";
Socket soc = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 9001);
soc.Connect(endPoint);
byte[] msgBuffer = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(path);
soc.Send(msgBuffer, 0, msgBuffer.Length, 0);
byte[] buffer = new byte[2000];
int rec = soc.Receive(buffer);

strRecieved = String.Format(Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer));
```

Comment: So you've created an IP socket to send to yourself? .. path in your example seems undefined. How big is path? more accurately, how big is msgbuffer? any chance that your receive buffer is only getting the 2000 bytes you told it to? and the message is bigger?

Comment: Exactly , the msg to be received is bigger , i don't receive the whole msg , what should i do to set the msg that may received as maximum ? Thanks

Comment: So why are you setting the buffer to 2000?

Comment: Yes , i am new to c# , i set as 2000, what should be done to set it to maximu ?

Comment: Not all the data will be received in one chunk.  You code has to continue reading until the end of data.  You must also include a method of determining the end.  So use one or more of following 3 methods 1) Ascii : Terminate data with character not part of message like '\n' or '\0'. 2) Ascii or Binary : Add byte count to beginning of message 3) Ascii or Binary : Fixed length messages.

Answer (score 1):

First of all. If you're implementing some kind of streaming feature ( tcp/udp/file ) you should consider using some kind of **protocol**.

What is a protocol? It's just a scheme to use when streaming data. Example:

**[4Bytes - length][lengthBytes - message][1Byte - termination indicator]**

Knowing the protocol you can read all of the incoming bytes simply as such :

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[4];
stream.ReadBytes(buffer, 0, 4); // cast that to int and read the rest

int packetLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0);
buffer = new byte[packetLen];
stream.ReadBytes(buffer, 0, buffer.Length); // all bytes that was sent
```

Remember that you have to subtract thease 4 bytes in the length before sending the message.

**EDIT:**

Simple example on how to send and receive data using shared **protocol**.

```
// sender.cs
string _stringToSend = "some fancy string";
byte[] encodedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_stringToSend);
List<byte> buffer = new List<byte>();
buffer.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(encodedString.Length));
buffer.AddRange(encodedString);
netStream.WriteBytes(buffer.ToArray(), 0, buffer.Count);
// netStream sent message in protocol [@LEN - 4Bytes][@MSG - @LENBytes]
// simply speaking something like: 5ABCDE

// receiver.cs
byte[] buffer = new byte[sizeof(int)];
netStream.ReadBytes(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
// receiver got the length of the message eg. 5
int dataLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0);
buffer = new byte[dataLen];
// now we can read an actual message because we know it's length
netStream.ReadBytes(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
string receivedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
// received string is equal to "some fancy string"
```

***Making it simpler***

This technique forces you to use desired protocol which in this example will be :

First 4 bytes `sizeof(int)` are indicating the length of the incoming packet
Every byte further is your packet until the end.

So right now you should make `ProtocolHelper` object:

```
public static class ProtocolHelper
{
    public byte[] PackIntoProtocol(string message)
    {
        List<byte> result = new List<byte>();
        byte[] messageBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
        result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(messageBuffer.Length), 0); // this is the first part of the protocol ( length of the message )
        result.AddRange(messageBuffer); // this is actual message
        return result.ToArray();
    }

    public string UnpackProtocol(byte[] buffer)
    {
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }
}
```

Now ( depending on method you've chosen to read from network ) you have to send and receive your message.

```
// sender.cs
string meMessage = "network message 1";
byte[] buffer = ProtocolHelper.PackIntoProtocol(meMessage);
socket.Send(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, 0);

// receiver.cs
string message = string.Empty;
byte[] buffer = new byte[sizeof(int)]; // or simply new byte[4];
int received = socket.Receive(buffer);
if(received == sizeof(int))
{
    int packetLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer);// size of our message
    buffer = new byte[packetLen]; 
    received = socket.Receive(buffer);
    if( packetLen == received ) // we have full buffer
    {
        message = PacketHelper.UnpackProtocol(buffer);
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(message); // output: "network message 1"
```

Comment: i am using tcp ip protocol,just check the source code i put ,

Comment: what is the variable netStream , am using sokcet.rceive(buffer) how can i pdate my code Thanks a lot

Comment: @m.rogaski in the class protocol helper what is the variable result what it its type ?

Answer (score 0):

You're limiting the size of received messages by 2KB as you're using `new byte[2000]`.
I think you could either:

- Size up you buffer to meet you message's size needs; and/or
- Split you message into more than one socket messages.

Given that 4-8K is a [good size for buffering socket messages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2811047/2944723) and assuming RAM size is not a issue I would start with that, say, `new byte[8000]`.

Also, you can send socket messages splitted in chunks. Maybe this is a good idea for the case. For example, if you have `msg` as the message (or object) you want to send:

```
private static async Task SendAnswer(Message msg, WebSocket socket)
{
    var answer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(msg).ToCharArray());

    var bufferSize = 8000;
    var endOfMessage = false;
    for (var offset = 0; offset < answer.Length; offset += bufferSize)
    {
        if (offset + bufferSize >= answer.Length)
        {
            bufferSize = answer.Length - offset;
            endOfMessage = true;
        }
        await socket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(answer, offset, bufferSize),
            WebSocketMessageType.Text, endOfMessage, CancellationToken.None);
    }
}
```

And when receiving, you can also split the reception in chunks, so you can control you buffer (and therefore you memory consumption). After hanlding the whole message, you should wait for another message from the client to do more stuff. [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

```
private async Task ReceiveMessage(WebSocket webSocket)
{
    var buffer = new byte[8000];
    var result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, CancellationToken.None);
    while (!result.CloseStatus.HasValue)
    {
        string msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer, 0, result.Count).ToArray());
        while (!result.EndOfMessage)
        {
            result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, CancellationToken.None);
            msg += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer, 0, result.Count).ToArray());
        }

        //At this point, `msg` has the whole message you sent, you can do whatever you want with it.
        // [...]
        //After you handle the message, wait for another message from the client
        result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, CancellationToken.None);
    }
    await webSocket.CloseAsync(result.CloseStatus.Value, result.CloseStatusDescription, CancellationToken.None);
}
```