# Not recieving all data in socket tcp

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I am working on socket C#. I've implemented a client server application using socket, but the problem is that the client doesn't receive all data sent by the server.

Here is the client application code. What should I do so that it would receive all data sent by the server?

```
strRecieved = "";
Socket soc = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 9001);
soc.Connect(endPoint);
byte[] msgBuffer = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(msgToberecieved);
soc.Send(msgBuffer, 0, msgBuffer.Length, 0);
byte[] buffer = new byte[2000];
int rec = soc.Receive(buffer);

strRecieved = String.Format(Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer));
```

Comment: " client doesn't receive all data " what do you expect to receive? and what have you received? how big is `buffer` ?

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41588439/client-server-socket-c-sharp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Client server socket C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41588439/client-server-socket-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

TCP is a streaming protocol, not a datagram protocol. This means that the data could be splitted over multiple receive-calls. It is also possible that multiple packets could be received within one receive call.

So you need a Packet Frame which should define the length of the data.

**For example:**

Create a header with a signatue(uint) and the datalength (uint) (so total 8 bytes). followed up with the data. (x bytes)

- First keep receiving data until you have the size of the header. (8 bytes)
- Check the signature if you're still aligned with the packets. *(take a magic number in your case)*
- Check the value of the length if is doesn't exceed a upper bound of your receive buffer.
- keep receiving data until you received all data.
- handle the data.
- repeat.

---

For parsing data you could use the [BitConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) or the [BinaryReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader(v=vs.110).aspx)

---

Another possibility is reading data until you have a 'stop' sign. For example `EOL` or `EOF` etc.

Comment: please am new to c# whould you please help update my code thnx a lot